# Migrate data from AWS OpenSearch to Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

I have an ~80 GB index on OpenSearch 1.3. I'm now deciding to move the index to an on-premise ElasticSearch 8.5.1 server. Here's what I've tried so far with no luck:

### Elasticdump

I tried using https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump, however, after many hours, it just exited mid-way, so I couldn't dump the entire index.

### Snapshot Repository

I followed [these instructions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-migrate-from-aws.html) and got the snapshot copied to S3. However, when I try to import the snapshot through Kibana, I get the following error:

> [XXX:YYY/ZZZ] the snapshot was created with Elasticsearch version [35.24.80] which is higher than the version of this node [8.5.1]

It seems as if the opensearch and elasticsearch versions are incompatible.

### Remote reindex

The last thing I tried was to use remote re-indexing which also failed:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "https://${opensearch_endpoint}:443"
    },
    "index": "${index}"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "${index}"
  }
}
```

Which returns this error:

> body={"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"No search type for [scan]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"No search type for [scan]"},"status":400}

Comment: Can you try to use a [source-only repository](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-source-only-repository.html) for your snapshot?

Comment: Remote reindex work in my case. Tried Elasticsearch 7.10 and 8.7 with a remote Opensearch 1.3 cluster. Both were able to remote reindex against Opensearch.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to make OpenSearch cluster compatible with the Elasticsearch API:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "compatibility" : {
    "override_main_response_version" : true
  }
}
```

If it does not work, you might want to try this with Logstash with the [opensearch input plugin](https://opensearch.org/blog/community/2022/05/introducing-logstash-input-opensearch-plugin-for-opensearch/).

Comment: The compatibility setting is true by default. It did not effect the version recorded in the snapshots, and I wasn't able to restore them in elasticsearch either.

Comment: Hard to say. May be you need to restore in an Elasticsearch 7.10 cluster first? Or I'd try a reindex from remote which might work but will probably require more time...

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to copy a snapshot from AWS opensearch to a docker based elasticsearch and got the same error. I ended up using a dockerized opensearch cluster instead which worked fine.